Specify async function in React prop expression
I have a Button which is disabled depending on an isSubmitDisabled function which is defined as async because it has an async part.
<Button type="button" disabled={isSubmitDisabled()}>Submit</Button>

const isSubmitDisabled = async () => {
    let result1 = await validatePart1(..);
    //...
    return finalResult ? true : false;
}

The validation works, but I can't use the prop expression syntax above for disabled=.
If I do disabled={isSubmitDisabled()}>
error: Type 'true | Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)
If I do disabled={await isSubmitDisabled()}>
error: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules
If I do a wrapper function per this example:
disabled = {
  (async () => {
    await isSubmitDisabled()
  })()
}

error: Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

You can't synchronously get a value from an asynchronous operation.
Use a state value to drive the UI, and update that state value from the asynchronous operation.  For example, consider a simple boolean state:
const [disableSubmit, setDisableSubmit] = useState(true);

Use that value to drive the button:
<Button type="button" disabled={disableSubmit}>Submit</Button>

Then you can update that state value from the asynchronous operation.  When/where that operation is invoked is up to you, in this case I'm just adding it to a useEffect which is executed once when the component first loads:
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    let result1 = await validatePart1(..);
    //...
    setDisableSubmit(finalResult ? true : false);
  })();
}, []);

Depending on the structure of what you're building, you may invoke this operation at a different time or even at multiple times.  But however you structure it, the point is to use state as an intermediary for asynchronous values.

Thanks David, I have one more general question. My understanding is, if I do await, then I'm synchronous. I am not asynchronous, because I'm waiting for the response, rather than coming back to it later. So why do I have to place await-containing code in an async function, and then invoke it as an async function? Am I misunderstanding the await and async concepts?

@geneb.: If you try to use await in a function that isn't async (and not in a top-level context which happens to support top-level await, which is fairly new) then you'll get an error.

Right, but I'm wondering why. If I'm doing await and waiting for the response, then I'm not async, I'm synchronous (in theory).

@geneb.: That theory is mistaken.  Asynchronous operations are asynchronous.  The await keyword is essentially (perhaps as an over-simplification, but a reasonable one) takes everything after the asynchronous operation in that function and wraps it in a callback to append to the Promise returned from that operation.

Ok thanks. So await is still asynchronous.

Create state to hold the disabled status.
Use useEffect to call the async function and update the state accordingly.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [submitDisabled, setSubmitDisabled] = useState(true);

const isSubmitDisabled = async () => {
  let result1 = await validatePart1();
  // ............
  const finalResult = result1 ? true : false;
  setSubmitDisabled(finalResult);

};

  useEffect(() => {   
    isSubmitDisabled ();
  }, []); // Run only once on component mount

  return (
    <Button type="button" disabled={submitDisabled}>Submit</Button>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

